# Android: Get ID of selected item from List Dialog created with a Cursor

Tags: android, listview, dialog, contacts

Inside my Activity class I'm overriding `onCreateDialog()` method 
with code somewhat like shown below.
The Dialog is now listing all items from my contact list.

When user clicks an item from this list I want to get the contact id
of the clicked item, that is the value of field `Phone._ID`.

Currently I'm getting only the position(index) of the selected Item inside
`which` argument of OnClickListener.
If the list was shown in a ListActivity I could probably use:

```
getListView().getItemIdAtPosition(which);
```

But here I'm unable to get a reference to the ListView.
How can I get the ID of clicked item from a list dialog created using cursor.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  String[] projection = new String[] {
                Phone._ID,
                Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                Phone.NUMBER
        };
  Cursor cursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, null);
  return new AlertDialog.Builder(ContactActivity.this)
            .setTitle("Select Contacts")
            .setCursor(cursor,
               new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

               /* User clicked on a contact item */

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "CLICKED-"+which,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
               }, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)
           .create();

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solutions for this myself. Below is the code that I'm using now.

I have declared the cursor of my contact list query as final.
and used the same cursor object inside the onClick method to
get the record at clicked position, using `moveToPosition()` method
of Cursor.
Also note that I have to use `cursor.moveToFirst();` at the bottom 
of onClick. Otherwise the dialog appears empty when I call up the
dialog again(I'm not sure why that happens).

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
String[] projection = new String[] {
            Phone._ID,
            Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            Phone.NUMBER
    };
final Cursor cursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            projection, null, null, null);
return new AlertDialog.Builder(ContactActivity.this)
        .setTitle("Select Contacts")
        .setCursor(cursor,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

           /* User clicked on a contact item */
            if(cursor.moveToPosition(which)){

             long contactId=cursor.getLong(0);
             String name=cursor.getString(1);
             String number=cursor.getString(2);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     "You selected: ["+contactId+"]" 
                      + name + " , " +number,
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                   .show();
            }
            cursor.moveToFirst();//Reset the position

          }
       }, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)
       .create();

}
```

But I don't feel like it is the right way to do this.
So I'm not marking this as the answer for this question.
I'll leave this question open for sometime and hope 
someone can come up with better suggestions.

**UPDATE:** Marked as answer because no response.